# Using pivot tables to group transactions

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have my bank account statement and what I would like to do is group the descriptions of the transactions together with their debit or credit and sum their total. I could then see that, e.g., for ebay.com my total debit was $2000, etc.

```
Description   Debit Credit
A              1
B                     1
A                     1
B              1
C              1
D                     1
A              1
```

What I want to do is use a pivot table

```
Description   Debit Credit
A                3
B                      2
C                1
D                      1
```

I am no able to do that, as I can't group the description and have additional debit and credit columns -- I get them all in rows with blanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario you are probably better off to use a regular table instead of a pivot table and turn on the totals row and display the SUM for your credits and debits and then use a filter on your description column (eg. ebay.com) to limit the rows displayed and summed in the total row at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

@Mike is always correct but since you asked for a pivot table:

[image: SU197309]

Note that this is based on your data input example, so does not match your data output example.